# Hashing problem in Julia with custom types

Tags: hash, julia

So I have defined a custom type `MyObject` and have overrided `hash` and `isequal` to ensure it works as a key in dictionaries.

So I have instantiated an object `a::MyObject`, and another object `a1::MyObject` that contains the same data content and hash to the same value, and `(a==a1)==true`.

Yet when I try to hash the tuples `(a,a)` and `(a1,a1)` they yields different values, can anyone explain to me what happen and how to fix it? (for example override another function, but it's the best not to override `hash(::Vector{MyObject})`)

Comment: how did you override `hash`? Specifically, did you override `hash(::MyObject)` rather than `hash(::MyObject, ::UInt)`?